# Button functioning properly on Chrome but not on IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive

I am currently doing a web interface. I am using the Angular framework

I have this add file button. Its supposed to only allow one file to be added. This works great on Chrome but not on IE 11.

Does anyone knows what might be creating this issue?

Code:

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}" ng-disabled="queue.length>= 1">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
  <span>Add file...</span>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" ng-disabled="disabled" accept=".zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit (a little, only one character) your code on JSFiddle

Check it:

http://jsfiddle.net/yk7x8kpL/

**CODE:**

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}" ng-disabled="queue.length>= 1">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add file...</span>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" ng-disabled="disabled" accept=".zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"/>
</span>
```

It works for me on IE 11

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marta. The problem is that the button should only allow one file to be added. Chrome does this. But IE allows multiple adds.

Comment: Don't worry. But... I tried it (and i trying again now) and... works for my IE 11 :S Only allow me select one file... I don't understand what happen. o.ó (version 11.0.9600.17416 over Windows)

Comment: Marta the problem is that the button should be disabled after you chose the file and click add! so after clicking open in the file explorer the add file button should be disabled

Comment: ¡Oh! I understand now... Sorry, my English is not very good, probably i don't understood before for it... Mmm... I wish you find a solution.

Comment: No problem Marta, perhaps I didn't explained it right, thanks anyway!!